# Problem with Django/Dajaxice and international characters

Tags: python, django, unicode, unicode-string

I am having a problem using Djajaxice with international characters...

I have a django template...in that template is the following select:

```
 <select name="region" id="id" onchange="Dajaxice.crc.regions('my_callback',{'data':this.value});">
         <option value="" selected="selected" ></option>
         {% for region in regions %}
              <option value="{{ region.region }}">{{ region.region }}</option>
         {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

As you can see on the onchange of the select I am calling the regions function and passing it two parameters. The name of the call back and the selected value

Here is the function in the ajax.py file

```
def regions(request, data):
    CityList = City.objects.filter(region__exact=data)
    out = "".join(['<option value="%s">%s</option>' % (c.city,c.city) for c in CityList])
    return simplejson.dumps(out)

dajaxice_functions.register(regions)
```

This works ok and calls, with the relevant data, my JavaScript function in the template with no problems when the name of the region does not have any international characters in it.

Say 'Antalya' for example. However when a region such as 'Muğla' comes along, it doesn't work. On close inspection the variable data contains 'Mu%u011Fla' and I can't seem to get it back to what I assume is the necessary format so that Django can access the model data correctly.

I have used the magic quotes at the top of the page, I have tried using unescaping it with data.decode('string-escape') and shoving it between utf-8 and back..but nothing I try seems to work...

Is this a Dajaxice, Django or python issue...or am I missing something really simple here?

I have been at it two days now, trying to figure this out....so many thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Cheers

Comment: is the string correct in the database and changes when you fetch it to render or its in the same distorted form in the database as well?

Comment: The string is ok in the database. I lift it out of the database via a view def...I stick it in the select above and then select it and call the onchange...it gets passed through some Dajaxice code to the function in ajax.py. I'm not sure if this is distorted as it leaves the select or when. The reason it won't match with the database and pull the region city records is because of its distortion.

Comment: If I pass the variable as is to the javascript function and unescape it in an alert, it is fine. But I don't want to do that, as I need it to be fine in the ajax.py method so that i can pull database records with it...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, fixed this...

So for anyone else using Dajaxice, and using international characters you should change line 10 in the Dajaxice.core.js file from the following:

send_data.push('argv='+escape(JSON.stringify(argv)));

to this:

send_data.push('argv='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(argv)));

and all works well.

Phew two days and a few hours of life slipped into the murky waters of code.... ...
help us all!